Possible to discretize / triangulate a polygon in RegionProduct - style?
Imagine I have a simple polygon:
p = {Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ (Pi/10*Range[10]);
points = Join[p*2, Reverse@p];
Graphics@Polygon@points


If I go by the manual and make RegionProduct from a 2d BoundaryMeshRegion and a 1d BoundaryMeshRegion, I get this:
bmr1 = BoundaryMeshRegion[points, 
   Line[Join[Range[Length[points]], {1}]]];
bmr2 = BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0}, {1}}, Point[{1, 2}]];
rp = RegionProduct[bmr1, bmr2]


Notice the way RegionProduct generates the mesh:
mcoords = MeshCoordinates[rp];
mcells = MeshCells[rp, 1][[All, 1]];
pick = Pick[Range@Length@mcoords, mcoords[[All, 3]], 1.];
Graphics@
 Thread@Line@(mcells[[Pick[Range@Length@mcells, 
         ContainsAny[#, pick] & /@ mcells, True]]] /. 
      AssociationThread[Range@Length@mcoords, mcoords])[[All, 
     All, {1, 2}]]



Question: How do I make the same style mesh from the
initial polygon?

DiscretizeRegion and ToElementMesh do it in a completely different way:
DiscretizeRegion[bmr1, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]

<< NDSolve`FEM`
ToElementMesh[Polygon[points], MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, 
  "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> Infinity]["Wireframe"]



Looks like you also need to mention you don't care about the triangle quality:
DiscretizeRegion[Polygon[points], MaxCellMeasure -> ∞, MeshQualityGoal -> 0]



Only work in versin 14.1. It seems that the new version 14.1 using the same discrete method as ToElementMesh.

Could you see if swapping TriangulateMesh in for DiscretizeRegion works? I don't have a lower version to try myself.

TriangulateMesh work fine in versions 12.2,12.3,13.3.1,14.1 but not in 14.0.

lol interesting.

You can use:
ToElementMesh[Polygon[points], "MaxCellMeasure" -> Infinity, 
  "MeshQualityGoal" -> 0]["Wireframe"]


